# Ansible best practice for unsafe variables?

Tags: ansible

Is there a better solution than this?

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: strip unsafe characters from ansible_virtualization_role value
      shell: |
        echo {{ ansible_virtualization_role }} | sed 's/[^a-z]//g'
      register: buf 
    - name: Set my_virtualization_role
      set_fact:
        my_virtualization_role={{ buf.stdout }}
```

ansible-lint reports "- no-changed-when  # Commands should not change things if nothing needs doing" so it would be nice to sanitise the unsafe variable without using the shell module but every pure Ansible solution I tried gave an unsafe variable error

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use ansible filters to acheive what you're trying to do - in particular, have a look at the `regex_replace` filter - see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions

In your example, you can write

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Set my_virtualization_role
      set_fact:
        my_virtualization_role={{ ansible_virtualization_role | regex_replace('[^a-z]', '') }}
```

Comment: Thanks olambert, that is a perfect answer to my question